# Heroku Dataclips hotkey (shortcut) to execute a query and set default security?

Tags: heroku

Is there a keyboard shortcut to execute a query through Heroku Dataclips?

Is there a way to set the default security to private instead of public?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A Heroku dataclip runs when you access its URL.

In the Settings of the dataclip, you can set its Security Permissions to "Only to authorized users" (although that feature is not avaiable if you are using a free/hobby tier database).